How to connect Django to SQL Server docker in Mac OS?
I cannot connect Django to SQL Server in mac OS. How to connect Django to SQL Server docker in Mac OS ?
Pip Install
pip install mssql-django
Setting:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'test1',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 1433,
        'USER': 'SA',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}

Run python3 manage.py runserver, it display error message as below. is there any way fix that error ?
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sql_server'
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1010, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
        raise _exception[1]
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
        autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
"/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 59, in <module>
        class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
        new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
        value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
        self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
        conn = self.create_connection(alias)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
        backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
        'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'


Your error doesn't seem related to any connection issue with SQL Server. It seems to be some error related to the auth.Group model and translations. Please [edit] and provide the following information: 1) Settings related to auth app and any custom user model if you have one. 2) Settings related to internationalization / translation. 3) Your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Actually, what is your Django version?

Aside... why are you using such an old version, ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server? Current releases are ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server. You might have less difficulty if you used Visual Studio Code with dev containers, since the dev containers themselves are Docker containers and will probably be very similar to the environments you deploy your app(s) to.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sql_server'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner


Django 5.......

The issue is the library installed. Django version < 3 and 'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc' config, requires django-mssql-backend library. However, on upgrading to modern Django versions(>3), use mssql-django library with 'ENGINE': 'mssql' as db config and "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
solution: pip install django-mssql-backend
also, confirm ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server is installed. on mac, run brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools

Django > 3
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

it is on Mac OS with Django 5

for django 5, use mssql-django library with 'ENGINE': 'mssql' as db config and "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"

error:
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 368, in get_new_connection
conn = Database.connect(connstr, **args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

kindly check on how to install odbc drivers on mac from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16 or simply run brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools 

brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
Warning: No available formula with the name "msodbcsql17".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for msodbcsql17.

brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update

File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 368, in get_new_connection
conn = Database.connect(connstr, **args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

use ip(127.0.0.1) instead of localhost

install pip install mssql-django if could not import mssql
